# Linker problems with eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, g++

I am making an eclipse project using both C and C++. My current problem is that I am defining the includes in the "paths and symbols" from the properties menu . I am setting the same paths in GNU C and in GNU C++ but it seems to don't be enough so that the compiler says "undefined reference" to the functions that needs that includes.

What am I missing?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I've realized I was introducing the -L and -l in a wrong way, now I am getting the error: /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/mizar/lib/usip/libsm_mizar.a when searching for -lsm_mizar. As I have seen in other posts it can be a problem of 32 bits/64 bits incompatibility. How could I solve it?

Comment: I don't get a question in your comment. Get correct version, for sure. /usr/local/ usually not distro-provided, but rather user-installed, so it seems that you have wrong version. Or, you compiling your program for different architecture (for 32bit on 64bit system, or even different type of CPU - you haven't told, sadly)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04  32 bits and I don't  have another version of this library , it is not specified if it is x86 or x64. the complet error list I am getting is: cannot find -lsm_mizar, make:***[test_application]Error 1, skipping incompatible /usr/local/mizar/lib/usip/libsm_mizar.a when searching for -lsm_mizar

Comment: OK determine the architecture of `/usr/local/.../libsm_mizar.a` from the command line using `file`.  Then check it matches the architecture you are building for.

Comment: File is not providing me info about the versión. I am only getting: libsm_mizar.a: current ar archive. I have also tried with objdump -f libsm_mizar.a | grep ^architecture and I have get rsa.usip.o:     file format elf32-little
architecture: UNKNOWN!, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x00000000

Comment: Looks like the archive is "broken" then.  Try extracting the object files from it (`(cd /tmp; ar x /path/to/file.a`) and then running `file` on them.

Comment: Solved! my problem was when adding the -l I missed to remove the "lib" ... from for instance libsm_mizar.a -> sm_mizar,